# How to make microwaves meals easier to empty

Tags: physical

There seems to be a problem with the common way to deliver a microwave meal.

From a flat, compartmentalised tray contents must be tipped or spooned onto a plate in order to be eaten. If there are two conjoined trays then one tray cannot be emptied on it's own without spilling the other. They are piping hot and this process can be difficult or even dangerous should scalding hot sauce get onto hands.

Is there a better design of container that would allow for the piping hot contents to be more easily transferred to a plate?

Comment: Surely this is what spatulas and ladles are designed for?

Comment: perhaps i am impatient, but they are far too shallow for any ladle to work effectively and spoons take ages

Comment: `... onto a plate in order to be eaten` Never did that

Comment: Yeah, why don't you just eat it out of the tray? That's what it's there for.

Comment: That's not the question !

Comment: The question seems almost pointless though - I'm assuming you're not a microwavable tray manufacturer.

Comment: Offtopic: @ColinSharpe - you've asked 31 questions on here, and only ever marked 4 as accepted? Can I ask why?

Comment: No I don't manufacturer microwave trays, I doubt you manufacturer washing machines either, yet that is your best answer ! I'm naturally curious about this subject and interested in good design solutions to problems.

Comment: I am with Brendon here. Use the right tool for the task. In the ladle section, you can usually buy a tool which is spoon-shaped (shallower than a laddle, but not flat like a spatula) and large enough (the "bowl" is maybe 10 cm long).

Comment: I'm not asking 'how do I empty' I'm asking 'how could the design be improved to facilitate emptying

Answer (score 0):

From a set like this one:

[image]

use the second tool to the right. It is like a spoon, but large enough.

Comment: See my main question please.

Comment: @ColinSharpe so, you are not asking how to solve a problem, but how to do a (probably complicated) redesign to the container so there will be a second solution to a problem which already has a good solution? This seems to go against the "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face." part of the StackExchange philosophy. This is what makes the network valuable for me - when I ask "How to do X", and experienced people tell me "in your case, you should be doing Y because it is easier". Else I could go read a tutorial.